# Heroku git update on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, railsinstaller

The Heroku toolbelt on windows shows that  the installed version has security vulnerabilities.

refers to this article https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/24/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x

Which advises to download myssygit latest  version. I dowloaded and installed to railsinstaller/git.

However after reboot still showing the older Heroku version not 1.9.5  as installed.

Looking in the  environmental variable and system path Heroku adds this path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin
```

However there is no git exe in this directory, how can I remove  the heroku version and let my upgraded system version be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you reinstall the toolbelt it'll come with a new version of git

Comment: Really I only installed the toolbelt last night.